# Working on England: NARIC

Tags: united-kingdom

For working in England, some advices are usually given:

- To homologate the graduation certificate in [NARIC](https://www.naric.org.uk/naric/individuals/?fbclid=IwAR2tZMwavyd1T_rkxvf1RqTgSYLPY_2TIgnPNWYWok-BCn-LerXwqkqDcAI),
- To have an English Certificate.

**Question**

Are those prerequisites very relevant for working on industries (such as any industry related to chemistry)? If so, is there any cheap English certificate that you recommend to do before travelling?

Comment: If you want to ask about moving to the UK, please ask on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @santimirandarp Which industries? To work in the UK, CEFR B1 is typically the minimum, and there is a list of approved tests and providers https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/777317/Approved_Secure_English_Language_Tests_and_Test_Centres__-_website.pdf  Specific employers may ask for a higher level of language skills

Comment: @Traveller and is it an indispensable document to work there? (I've no certificate but I can communicate quite well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need (or process that I am aware of) for getting an official certification of the equivalency of your degree with a UK degree. (Update: It turns out there *is* a process; see the updated question).  If you graduated from a well-known University the employer will have heard of it; if not, you could try looking at the German "anabin" site (I think google translate makes a fair fist of it), to see if the Germans have declared your university equivalent to a German one (which will be accepted as the equivalent of an English one).

In general UK employers are less interested in your degree, than in your experience.  If you have just graduated, you will find it *very* hard to find a job.

I think you are going to need pretty good English (B1 at least, and preferably B2) to find a job in England (unless you have *outstanding* experience).  Again, the formal certification is less important than how easily your potential employer can read your application, and how easy your interviewer finds it to communicate with you.

Comment: I've added the homologation service, called NARIC...